# Carrierwave #avatar? returns false when it should be returning true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

Project is here: https://github.com/pmatsinopoulos/test_carrierwave

My project is a Ruby On Rails project that uses `ActiveRecord` and the gem `carrierwave` to store avatars on `User` model.

I have a test case in which the `#avatar?` returns `false` when it should be returning `true`.

Here is the test case:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "avatar" do
    @user = User.new
    @user.name = "George"
    @user.save!

    assert_equal false, @user.avatar?

    # set avatar
    @user.avatar = File.open("#{Rails.root}/test/files/lion-30-x-30.jpg")
    @user.save!

    assert_equal true, @user.avatar?

    # remove avatar
    @user.remove_avatar!
    @user.save!

    assert_equal false, @user.avatar?

    # add back again
    @user.avatar = File.open("#{Rails.root}/test/files/lion-30-x-30.jpg")
    @user.save!

    assert_equal true, @user.avatar?
  end
end
```

Last test fails.

Does anybody have any clue? Any help?

Comment: The only case I can think is that the second file doesn't exist.

Comment: The same error occurs even if you use the same file. I am going to change that in the question to avoid misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open issue on carrierwave:
https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/401

It provides a workaround (by https://github.com/ajahongir):

```
# remove avatar
@user.remove_avatar!
@user.save!

assert_equal false, @user.avatar?

# add back again
@user = User.find @user
@user.avatar = File.open("#{Rails.root}/test/files/lion-30-x-30.jpg")
@user.save!
```